# Load Meta box value into div AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to load video from custom field value ( which is embedded `<iframe>`). Click any button and play that video.

> **Console log:** As i click any button its goes to jquery line `console.log(result);`. Give no output related to buttons.

**What missing and how to make it working-able?**

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><button class="play_next"  data-meta-key="url-1">Video 1</button></li>
    <li><button class="play_next"  data-meta-key="url-2">Video 2</button></li>
    <li><button class="play_next"  data-meta-key="url-3">Video 3</button></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.play_next' ).on('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var meta_key = $( this ).data( 'metaKey' );
        var post_id = $( this ).data( 'post_id' );

        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { 
                action: 'wpse_296903_call_meta',
                meta_key: meta_key,
                post_id: post_id,
            },
            success: function( result) {
                $( '#output' ).append( result );
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
function wpse_296903_call_meta() {
if( isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && isset( $_POST['meta_key'] )) {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $meta_key = $_POST['meta_key'];

    if ( in_array( $meta_key, ['url-1', 'url-2', 'url-3'] ) ) {
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );
    }
}
wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_296903_call_meta', 'wpse_296903_call_meta' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_296903_call_meta', 'wpse_296903_call_meta' );
```

**Enqueue_script:**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'cf_enqueue_scripts' ) ) :
  function cf_enqueue_scripts() {

wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js');

wp_deregister_style( 'style' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'));

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js');

wp_localize_script('script', 'ajaxobject', array(
   'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
));

 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cf_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Looks like you're sending a GET request but trying to catch $_POST values!

Comment: Even with POST request. its give same output in console

Comment: Make sure there are no console errors and this handle looks wrong: `jquer`. Do you have two jquery instances now? Why are you using a theme bundled jquery, instead of the default one in core?

Comment: This looks wrong `.data( 'metaKey' )` (isn't it `meta-key`?) and there's no `.data('post_id')`. You have to go through the code step-wise and check the values etc.

Comment: Do you post answer? i am working on it from couple of days but not works for me

Comment: @birgire Yes that's my bad advice. I quoted the documentation the last time he asked about this but in checking again I realise that's specific to jQuery 3+. @M.Arif. Change that to `'meta-key'`.

Comment: @M.Arif That doesn't mean you ask the question again.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I think you need to update your answer. Its not working i also spend my time on it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes this is definitely a duplicated one, so I vote to close this one. M. Arif: Please continue this in your other question - best of luck.

Comment: @M.Arif I have updated the original answer to fix the issue birgire raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add data attribute `data-post-id` for the post id. Eg.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><button class="play_next"  data-meta-key="url-1" data-post-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">Video 1</button></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

2. Missing data attributes in js. `$( this ).data( 'metaKey' );` should be `$( this ).data( 'meta-key' );` and `$( this ).data( 'post_id' );` should be `$( this ).data( 'post-id' );` E.g.

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.play_next' ).on('click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var meta_key = $( this ).data( 'meta-key' );
        var post_id = $( this ).data( 'post-id' );
        ...
    });
});
```

3. Use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`  Instead of `$_POST` E.g.

**PHP:**

```
function wpse_296903_call_meta() {
if( isset( $_GET['post_id'] ) && isset( $_GET['meta_key'] )) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $meta_key = $_GET['meta_key'];
    ...
}
wp_die();
}
```

**Additional Notes**

- Add nonce while using Ajax.
- Sanitize input